# Oracle Data Pump Import imports LONG with spaces after evfery character

Tags: oracle, datapump

I'm importing an 11g oracle schema into a 10g database using data pump import/export. The problem is that on one of my LONG columns, when importing the data data pump seems to put a space after every character, so the data goes from looking like this:

```
{somedata}
```

To this:

```
{ s o m e d a t a }
```

This obviously breaks the application that is trying to use this database. Is there a way round this?

Comment: Are you moving from *nix to Windows (or vice-versa)?  Are the character encodings on the 2 machines the same?

Comment: I'm exporting from a windows 7 PC to a windows server 2008. The character encodings are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving data from a newer version of the database to an older version. Data Pump can do this, but not by default.  Did you specify `VERSION=10.2` (or whatever) when you ran the export?  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#i1007148).

Comment: I specified VERSION=10 but I did not know you could specify minor version numbers like 10.2 - I will try this.

Comment: This worked! When I specified version=10.2, the problem went away! Thanks!